# jQuery show inner div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an inner div which hi hidden. When I hover over the outter div I wish to show the inner. I am having difficulty doing this. I have tried a few variations but still cant get it.

I will have multiple outer div's on the page also.

```
<div class='outdiv'>
    <h1>Content</>
    <div class='innerdiv'></div>
</div>
<div class='outdiv'>
    <h1>Content</>
    <div class='innerdiv'></div>
</div>
<div class='outdiv'>
    <h1>Content</>
    <div class='innerdiv'></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
        $("div.listingContainer").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).parent().siblings(".saveCompare").show();
        }).mouseout(function(){

        });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Uhmmm … Did you oversimplify your HTML in the example? Your jQ selectors don't match your markup at all.

Comment: Also, there's a CSS only solution for your problem: `.outdiv:hover .innerdiv { display: block }` – why bother using JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using jQuery for this?
I'd go with a css hover for this one

```
.outdiv:hover .innerdiv {
  display: block; // adjust for your method of hiding the div
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
    $("div.outerDiv").mouseover(function() {
        $('div.innerDiv', this).show();
    });
```

or to show / hide

```
    $("div.outerDiv").hover(function() {
        $('div.innerDiv', this).show();
    },
    function() {
        $('div.innerDiv', this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("div.outdiv").hover(function()
{
    $(this).find(".innerdiv").show();
},
function()
{
    $(this).find(".innerdiv").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a second parameter to `$()` which specifies the context of the selection - [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

```
$('.outdiv').hover(function ()
{
    $('.innerdiv', this).show();
}, function ()
{
    $('.innerdiv', this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pGF3x/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".outdiv").hover(function()
{
        $(this).find(".innerdiv").show();
},
function()
{
         $(this).find(".innerdiv").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.outdiv',this).hover(function () {
                $('.innerdiv',this).css('opacity', '0');
            }, function () {
                $('.innerdiv').css('opacity', '1.0');
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Do like this with JQuery**